# Typescript, using classes without constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, class, typescript, constructor

While working with the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on the Angular website I found the following syntax (shortly):

```
class Hero {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}

const aHero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Superman'
}

console.log(aHero instanceof Hero); //false
```

What would be the point in doing this? when if I check the type of "aHero", it is only a common object and not a "Hero" type. Would it be better just initializing an object with a constructor?:

```
class Hero {
  constructor(id: number, name: string) {}
}
```

Comment: Good question. The answer is the tutorial promotes a bad practice. `Hero` should be an `interface`.

Comment: Todd Motto has a [great article](https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript) explaining the difference and when/why to use `interface` vs `class`

Comment: can you add a reference to the section with this code?

Comment: IMO this is a really bad example for newcomers, already reported on github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21186

Comment: Sure!, the code here is a bit different than from what I posted. [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1)

Comment: good spot! that's a bad practice - one should be using interfaces in those cases.

Comment: Actually it's a promoted as a good practice in the angular guide at least. Interfaces have no runtime correspondent and thus no injection token for angular to use. Also in typescript classes behave as interfaces as well. That is not very good OOP but it makes sense more sense in typescript and angular. https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Comment: @toskv I just checked - indeed in the tutorial they declare a class, then declare a variable of that class, initializing it with a plain object. Exactly as OP explained in the question, there is a problem - runtime behavior does not match compile time declaration: `aHero instanceof Hero` is false, while `aHero` is declared as `aHero: Hero`. It will break in more spectacular ways when any method is added to the class. This can't be good practice.

Comment: @toskv yes, interfaces cant be used for DI in angular, but this use case has nothing to do with that topic

Comment: @artem I agree, in this case the use of the class is just a bad application of the style guide. I was trying to point out a potential source for the bad code. Maybe the guide could be improved as well. Suggest Using classes instead of interfaces only for Injectables.

Comment: In my perhaps limited worldview, a `class` is meant to create instances of using `new`. I'm sure Angular has some good reason for jumping through hoops and creating workarounds for problems that it created itself, because that's what Angular is really good at :)

Answer (score 22):

You can use class as a type which is the way you're using it. So, whether Hero is an interface or class it doesn't matter because you're using it as a type.

```
class Hero { id: number; name: string }
```

or

```
interface Hero { id: number; name: string }
```

The following doesn't concern whether Hero is a class or interface

```
let hero: Hero = { id: 1, name: 'me' }
```

Where `interface` and `class` differentiate is `interface` is only for you, it doesn't get transpiled into javascript. A `class` does and you cannot `new` an `interface`.

Constructor or no Constructor, if you `new` it then it is an `instanceof`. Try it again with this

```
let hero = new Hero();
```

Your `instanceof` log will be `true` because you did create an instance of Hero with the key word `new`.

Answer (score -3):

I know this question has been answered before but as far as object oriented code goes it was always like this.

I believe you can do this without a constructor:

```
let hero: Hero = { ID: 1, Name: 'goku'};
```

but if you want to instantiate with the constructor you can do this in the class

```
class Hero
{
    //notice optional parameters. You have more flexibility this way.
    constructor(id?: number, name?: string)
    {  
      this.ID = id;
      this.Name = name;
    }

    ID: number;
    Name: string
}
```

And do this with the implementation

```
let hero: Hero = new Hero(1,'goku');
let hero2: Hero = { ID: 2, Name: 'superman' }
```

Comment: The above is incorrect, as the above answers hero = new Hero , creates an instance of the class Hero, where hero2: hero is an object with a type of Hero.