# angular interface style guide - unclear recommendations

Tags: angular, typescript

I've read the [Angular style guide for interfaces](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces), and there are two recommendations there that are completely unclear to me:

> Consider using a class instead of an interface for services and declarables (components, directives, and pipes).
>
> Consider using an interface for data models.
>
> Why? A class can act as an interface (use implements instead of extends).
>
> Why? An interface-class can be a provider lookup token in Angular dependency injection.

In the first case, is there even an alternative to defining a service as a class?

In the second case, the recommendation seems contrary to Angular's Tour of Heroes tutorial (has it been updated lately?), where the Hero model is defined as a class, like so:

```
export class Hero {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}
```

And also, what is an `interface-class` and what does it mean a `provider lookup token`?

I think that several examples could really clarify things here.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript, using classes without constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996399/typescript-using-classes-without-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a little out of context but what they are referring to is using a class (model) for retrieving data i.e. `this.service.getSomething().subscribe((model: myModel) => model);`.
2. An interface-class is a class that acts as an interface a.k.a. a model.
3. A provider lookup token is how angular knows what provider to use. There is a more in-depth explanation [here](https://toddmotto.com/angular-dependency-injection#tokens-and-dependency-injection).