# Angular 7 map firebase UserInfo to custom User model

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication, angular7

I am new to angular 7, I trying to get the current authenticated user from firebase and map to my own `User` model (without constructor in `User`).

In firebase API:

```
interface UserInfo {
  displayName: string | null;
  email: string | null;
  phoneNumber: string | null;
  photoURL: string | null;
  providerId: string;
  uid: string;
}
```

In my own model:

```
export class User{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  contactNo: string;
}
```

My `UserService`

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
  ) {}

  getAuthUser(): Observable<User> {

    // this part is not working, how to map to User without changing User constructor?
    return this.fireAuth.authState.map(authData => new User({name: authData.displayName}));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [**Angular Style Guide**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-03-03):

> Consider using an interface for data models.

That being said, you can do this if you are willing to follow that style guide:

Create a `User` `interface` with optional fields:

```
export interface User{
  name?: string;
  email?: string;
  contactNo?: string;
}
```

And in your Service you can simply do this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {}

  getAuthUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.fireAuth.authState.map(authData => ({
      name: authData.displayName
    }));
  }

}
```

Comment: I try following the above suggestion for `map`(without changing data model to interface) and it says `Type 'Observable<{ name: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'.`.

Comment: Did you make an interface and made all the fields in the `User` `interface` optional?

Comment: Oh, i mark all fields in `User` as optional and it works, why do we have to mark all fields as optional?

Comment: You don't have to. That's just a way to let you define the type with less fields if you like.

Comment: @hades, it's because the User type wouldn't necessarily have all the fields all the time. As in this case, the name field is available. In some cases, it won't be available. For eg when you implement Phone Sign-in. So it's better to keep all of them as optional.

Comment: If the AuthState is being used, the field will always be "there" it just may not have a value.

Comment: @OneLunchMan, thanks for articulating what I meant in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

**After the question was edited**

I still recommend the "before the question was edited" answer, but to answer the question:

`new User({name: authData.displayName})` cannot work without adjusting the constructor. A class has a default constructor, `User()` in your case, that accepts no arguments. If you have to or want to use a class instead of an interface (noted below), then there are a few *workarounds* you should be able to do.

Rough examples:

```
// object "as"
authData => <User>{name: authData.displayName, ... other props}

// object "as" 2
authData => {name: authData.displayName, ... other props} as User

// new user, return after changing props
authData => {
    const user = new User();
    user.name = authData.displayName;
    // ...the rest
    return user;
}

// "builder" method (basically a constructor)
function buildUser(name: string, ...other props) {
    const user = new User();
    user.name = authData.displayName;
    // ...the rest
    return user;
}
```

---

**Before the question was edited**
If you don't want to use a constructor and the class is just a model with no extra methods, I recommend using an interface.

```
// interface
export interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  contactNo: string;
}

// inside map
authData => {name: authData.displayName, ...<other props>}

// inside map with type checking 1
authData => <User>{name: authData.displayName, ...<other props>}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016696/10747134) has more details.

Comment: thanks, your way works too, but after reading your link, i still confuse with the benefit of using `interface` over `class` for data model, mind to explain some briefly?

Comment: I'd just say that you don't really need a class if it doesn't really add any value to your specific case. If you think you just need a way to type your User Data via a Model and Nothing more than that, making a class won't make much sense. Also since interfaces aren't compiled, they won't be available in your main bundle. Even Angular recommends using `interface`s for Data Models as I've linked in my answer.

Comment: There are multiple benefits. Basically an interface is just dev/compile time sugar that gives you a lot of benefits like type checking, but is not included in the final js. As well, it allows you to more easily loosely set the properties on an object `<ABC>{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}` and allow it to work for anything that accepts an object that requires those two fields. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/interfaces.html
Ex: `fun1(param: {a: string})` `fun2(param: {a: string, b: string}` `fun3({a, b, c}: ABC)`.

Comment: And here is a simple example (es5) of that in action: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20user%20%3D%20new%20User('')%3B%0D%0Ainterface%20User2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20user2%20%3D%20%3CUser2%3E%7Bname%3A%20''%7D%3B